# Combine multiple rows into single row using Teradata

Tags: sql, recursion, teradata, aggregate-functions, rollup

I want to achieve single row output from multiple rows for below 3 cases using Teradata SQL Assistant. Can someone please help me framing a generic query that can handle all of below 3 cases. Any help is highly appreciated.

[Problem_statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTNW2.png)

Case - 1:

Existing Data

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
1   100217  0110527 Camera  1.0.02R22   My Camera 5 10/25/2015 17:56:09.000 10/29/2015 23:59:59.000
2   100217  0110527 Camera  1.0.02R22   Pool    10/30/2015 18:00:13.000 9/27/2016 23:59:59.000
```

Data I want

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT

1   100217  0110527 Camera  1.0.02R22   Pool    10/25/2015 17:56:09.000 9/27/2016 23:59:59.000
```

Case - 2:

Existing Data

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
1   10006   0161969 Peripheral-router   V1.2.2.79   Network Peripheral  12/17/2014 23:12:32.000 7/8/2015 23:59:59.000
2   10006   0161969 Peripheral-router   V1.2.2.82   Network Peripheral  7/9/2015 21:34:39.000   2/16/2016 23:59:59.000
10006   0161969 Peripheral-router   V1.2.2.86   Network Peripheral  2/17/2016 16:27:12.000  8/17/2016 23:59:59.000
```

Data I want

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
10006   0161969 Peripheral-router   V1.2.2.86   Network Peripheral  12/17/2014 23:12:32.000 8/17/2016 23:59:59.000
```

Case 3: Where some records have device start dt > device end dt

Existing Data

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back Door   5/8/2019 15:55:30.000   6/2/2019 23:59:59.000
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back Door   6/3/2019 22:31:06.000   6/25/2019 23:59:59.000
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back Door   6/26/2019 15:52:57.000  7/19/2019 23:59:59.000
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back Door   7/21/2019 03:40:11.000  7/20/2019 23:59:59.000
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back    7/21/2019 13:03:56.000  10/23/2019 23:59:59.000
```

Data I want

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
100526  84990534    Camera  3.0.02.54   Back    5/8/2019 15:55:30.000   10/23/2019 23:59:59.000
```

Case 4: Where some records have device start dt > device end dt

Existing Data

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/13/2017 12:24:42.000  8/20/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/21/2017 08:49:08.000  8/25/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/27/2017 02:42:46.000  8/26/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/28/2017 06:33:50.000  8/28/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/30/2017 02:35:32.000  8/31/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/2/2017 00:25:05.000   9/1/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/3/2017 03:33:28.000   9/3/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/4/2017 18:35:45.000   9/8/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/10/2017 11:22:54.000  10/16/2018 23:59:59.000
```

Data I want

```
ACCOUNT_ID  ACCOUNT_NUMBER  DEVICE_TYPE FIRMWARE_VERSION    LABEL   DEVICE_START_DT DEVICE_END_DT
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/13/2017 12:24:42.000  8/26/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/28/2017 06:33:50.000  8/28/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  8/30/2017 02:35:32.000  9/1/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/3/2017 03:33:28.000   9/8/2017 23:59:59.000
1000027 84957524    Peripheral-gateway  ?   Network Peripheral  9/10/2017 11:22:54.000  10/16/2018 23:59:59.000
```

Edit:
The scenario I want to achieve is like below:

1. The examples given are all history records(SCD Type - 2),all the active records will have device end dt as 
   '9999-12-31 00:00:00' like some dates in future. We will not consider active records. Idea is to eliminate rollup duplicates 
   for expired records, we will not consider firmware_version to consider dups. Apart from firmware_version,device_start_dt
   & device_end_dt all the other values are same.
2. We will only consider expired records and will maintain minimum of info about expired records since data volume is 
   large.

Suppose a device have 5 such instances as below with firmware version, device start date and device end date 
respectively, in ideal case device start date of second instance = (device end date of instance 1 + 1)

instance 1: V1.2.2.79  10/23/2012   11/26/2012
instance 2: V1.2.2.80  11/27/2012   11/28/2012
instance 3: V1.2.2.95  11/29/2012   07/23/2017
instance 4: V1.2.2.98  07/24/2017   12/29/2018
instance 5: V1.2.2.99  12/30/2018   09/02/2019

for above example i want the output like latest firmware version, device start date(earliest or oldest) and 
latest date when it expired as device end date

output:
V1.2.2.99  10/23/2012  09/02/2019

Comment: The question is not clear. Please edit it and create a minimal dataset input and desired output. Plus add why this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Roee. I have explained my scenario in detail in comment section.

Comment: Your example data doesn't look like a SCD2, there are gaps between previous end and current start and end is less than start in some cases. Do you have dates or timestamps?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There are few mismatches as for fewer records it was created in GMT timezone where creation date of the record was lesser than record start date. Device_start_dt & device_end_dt are timestamp here but you can consider either date or timestamp, not an issue.

Comment: For case 4 we are considering those records having device start date > (device end date + 1) for creating a single instance. For fewer cases device start date is greater than device end date , those mostly for same day expired records due to timezone bug, but we can ignore those and select whatever value is there in table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software **you have written**, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should **include the code you've written** and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems YOUR CODE has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark. You seem to want mainly data from the latest row, just the start date from the first row:

```
select ACCOUNT_ID
  ,ACCOUNT_NUMBER
  ,DEVICE_TYPE
  ,FIRMWARE_VERSION
  ,LABEL
  ,first_value(DEVICE_START_DT) -- date from first row
   over (partition by ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DEVICE_TYPE --??
         order by DEVICE_END_DT desc) 
  ,DEVICE_END_DT
from tab
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by ACCOUNT_ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DEVICE_TYPE --??
         order by DEVICE_END_DT desc) = 1 -- latest row
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer dnoeth. I have explained my scenario in detail in comment section.